# Comment Link from get_comments()?

Tags: comments

I've got to update a bit of sloppy code that shows the 5 most recent comments across the entire blog. The code is using WordPress' `get_comments()` method, which doesn't appear to return comment id's, or comment links (direct links to comments within posts via the hash-tag).

How can I collect more information about the particular comments, and make them links to the actual comments within their parent pages?

```
<h3>Recent Comments</h3>
<ul>
<?php $comments = get_comments(array('status'=>'approve','number'=>'5')); ?>
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
  <?php $post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID, 'OBJECT'); ?>
  <li><?php print $comment->comment_author; ?> on 
      <a href="<?php print get_permalink($post->post_ID); ?>">
        <?php print $post->post_title; ?>
      </a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This is located on the front page of the site, outside of the loop.

Comment: You should probably use [`get_comment_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_link)... See my answer to a similar question [**here**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175007/1044).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close! Add #comment-`<?php comment_id(); ?>`to the href to append the anchor link

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID);?>#comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
     <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: I had saw that function but thought (wrongly) that it would only work within a real loop, and not necessarily a call to `get_comments()`. Thanks for clearing that up for me!