# Get Comments: Direct link to specific comment + post title

Tags: comments

I'm pretty sure that this can be solved quite easy, but for some reason I just can't get it to work.

My current code looks like this:

```
<?php   $comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
<ul id="recent_comments">
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
<li><p><strong><?php
        $title = get_the_title($comment->post_ID);
        echo get_avatar( $comment, '45' );
echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?></strong>&nbsp;commented on <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->post_ID); ?>" rel="external nofollow" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"> <?php echo $title; ?></a>: <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 45 ); ?> (...)</p></li>
<?php }  ?>
</ul>
```

It works fine, but it only displays the post title and a link to it. I'd like to have the post title displayed, but have it linked directly to the specific comment.

I suppose you'd use something like that:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->ID); ?>#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" title="on <?php echo $comment->post_title; ?>"></a>
```

I tried to implement this into the code above somehow. It works, but it suddenly shows the title of a post where the comment doesn't belong to.

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$comment->post_ID` use `$comment->comment_post_ID`. Your code will look like following:

```
<?php   $comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
<ul id="recent_comments">
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
<li><p><strong><?php
        $title = get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID);
        echo get_avatar( $comment, '45' );
echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?></strong>&nbsp;commented on <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>" rel="external nofollow" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"> <?php echo $title; ?></a>: <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 45 ); ?> (...)</p></li>
<?php }  ?>
</ul>
```

You were doing right about adding comment's div id at the end of URL for creating individual comment links. You need to add `#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>` at the end of post permalink.

Here is how the anchor tag should look like.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>#comment-<?php echo $comment->comment_ID; ?>" rel="external nofollow" title="<?php echo $title; ?>"> <?php echo $title; ?></a>
```

Comment: Hello. Yes, this works, of course, but what I want is not only the link to the post, but also the specific comment as in "http://....post-title/comment-#12". Do you know how to achieve this? And thank you very much :)

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use this: [`get_comment_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_link)... and do something like this in your `href` value:

```
<?php echo get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID); ?>
```

Because if you use **pagination** for your comments, this **can automatically determine the page the comment is in** as well.